# Spring-integration with tibco Rendezvous

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, tibco-rv

I am working standalone spring-boot application that needs to connect to a topic of a [Tibco RV messaging system](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/tibco-tutorial-difference-between-tibco.html)(Not Tibco EMS). I would like to know if there is a way to connect a spring application with the Tibco RV messaging system? Whatever examples I have seen are using Tibco EMS but can't find any documentation for connecting a spring application in a peer-to-peer messaging system like Tibco RV.

Any kind of help in this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link is wrong in your question. Anyway looking into the Internet there is no JMS bridge for Tibco RV and we don't have choice unless use their [Java API](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/rendezvous/8.3.1_january_2011/pdf/tib_rv_java_reference.pdf) from the custom Channel Adapter implementations. Yes, for publishing messages to the RV we would need only `TibrvTransport` in the `@ServiceActivator` method. But for the `TibrvListener` we definitely need to implement `MessageProducerSupport`.

Comment: sorry, fixed the link.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Can you please share some code how you implemented it?

Comment: See for example, this one: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-amqp/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/amqp/inbound/AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java